# How to add numerical values together from keys with the same name in one object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have created an object and want to sum the numerical values if the key is duplicated in an object

```
var obj = {
  "orange": 1,
  "apple": 1,
  "grape": 1,
  "orange": 1
};
```

output should be

```
obj = { "orange": 2, "apple": 1, "grape": 1 }
```

Comment: Did you try to do it yourself ? BTW obj is invalid object !!!

Comment: Note that objects can only contain each property once, so your first object will not be in the format you expect as the first `orange` property will be overwritten. Therefore your desired output cannot be reached from it.

Comment: `output should be` - why?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - it's "valid" (no errors, except in strict mode) just not correct

Comment: @JaromandaX true, in the sense that it doesn't error. I'll amend my wording.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like:

```
BugOfThings = function() {}
BugOfThings.prototype.add = function(thing, count) {
    count = count || 1;
    this[thing] = (this[thing] || 0) + count;
}
var bug = new BugOfThings();
bug.add("orange", 1);
bug.add("apple", 1);
bug.add("grape", 1);
bug.add("orange", 1);
```

But in this case output will be containts a **add** field

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
var tagSelected = [{ "orange": 1, "apple": 1, "grape": 1, "orange": 1 }];
var tagSelectedTotal = [];

$.each(tagSelected, function() {
  var fount = false;
  var tag = this;
  $.each(tagSelectedTotal, function() {
    if( this.name == tag.name ) {
      this.value = parseInt(this.value) + parseInt(tag.value);
      found = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if( !found ) {
    tagSelectedTotal.push( tag );
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{ "orange": 1, "apple": 1, "grape": 1, "orange": 1 }
```

This is impossible <s>(illegal?)</s> in <s>JSON</s> JS I guess.

**[JSON IS NOT JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)**

It will just output

```
{ "orange": 1, "apple": 1, "grape": 1}
```

So basically your question can't be answered.

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Why this isn't an answser?

Comment: @JaromandaX why JSON not relevant? The syntax the object describes is JOSN actually.

Comment: The syntax is an object - it has *nothing* to do with JSON.

Comment: @JaromandaX Whaat? From wikipedia I see "JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)"

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) ?

Comment: That's right, it's a notation method to transcribe an object to a string. For example, JSON: `var json = '[{ "foo": "bar" }]'`. Object: `var obj = { foo: 'bar' };`. The difference is subtle, but very important.

Comment: Just remove the var obj in front of the code and you have JSON so why are you bothering? + the object has key wrapped in quotes which are not useful in that case. It's clearly JSON notation.

Comment: No removing the `var` will not give you JSON. If you're confused by this I would strongly suggest you read some articles on the subject.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan var json = '{ "foo": "bar" }' is still valid, why wrap the bracket?

Comment: @JaromandaX it's Rory McCrossan that has written var json = '[{ "foo": "bar" }]' to give me an example of JSON.

Comment: @JaromandaX Also, saying that JSON is a string? Where does that come from?

Comment: @JaromandaX JSON is a format, JavaScript is interpreting it as a string, and so he does for XML. You are making up word trying to explains something I already understand. Ofc JavaScript is not JSON. Ofc they behave like two different languages. But as JSON heavily relies of JS object notation, it's easier to validate what OP asked from a JSON validator.

Comment: @JaromandaX I was saying "my bad, It's not written in the french wikipedia page I read" but you edited your message - - and not you've deleted it xD

Comment: And not he deleted all of its comments - - must have been a politician in another life xD